# Correct way to deploy play framework app to prod systems

Tags: playframework

I compiled my app with following setting in application.conf file

```
# Application mode
# ~~~~~
# Set to dev to enable instant reloading and other development help.
# Otherwise set to prod.
application.mode=prod
%prod.application.mode=prod
```

I then use the cmd

```
play war myapp -o myapp --zip
```

Then deployed to production.

When I looked at the tomcat/webapps/myapp/web-inf directory
I can see the java classes as well as settings files from Netbeans(used Netbeans as my IDE)

Is there a verbose that I should use when compiling and creating WAR file from Prod system deployment?

Comment: do you have to use a WAR file, or can you deploy as a standard Play app...

Comment: @Codemwnci: How would I deploy as standard play app on Tomcat ?

Comment: you wouldn't on tomcat. A standard Play app deployment is on the inbuilt Netty server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to use the `--exclude` flag that will not package the folders you mention.

You could go about it as:

`play clean && play war --%prod --exclude folders:separated:by:colon -o myWar --zip`

Answer (score 0):

First of all "play war" will, as I understand it precompile all your code as Play cannot compile on the fly when it is deployed in a servlet container. So it should be .class files included in the resulting .war.

Secondly, I would suggest having your projects checked out at two different locations on your disk. One for development using Netbeans (or any other IDE), and one for building deployables. When you are ready for another release, make sure you have commited (and "pushed" if using DSCM e.g GIT or HG). From the folder containing the "build" version of your project, pull all changes from SCM and build it from the command line. Never ever open the build version in your IDE as it will add all sorts of files to your build folder.

Final hint: make sure all IDE-specific files are ignored by your SCM. For GIT, add filename patterns to be ignored to a .gitignore file in the root folder of your project (HG: .hgignore, svn: use the svn:ignore property).